# .NET 6.0 - retrieving string array from a specific appsettings.json file

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, appsettings

I have two appsettings files in my project: `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`. I have string arrays in both files: two developers' e-mails in the Development file and seven production e-mails in the main appsettings.json file.

appsettings.Development.json:

```
"Contacts": {
    "Emails": [ "email1", "email2" ],
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
"Contacts": {
    "Emails": [ "email3", "email4", "email5", "email6", "email7", "email8", "email9" ],
}
```

I have this setup in my Program.cs:

```
WebApplicationOptions opts = new WebApplicationOptions
{
   ApplicationName = "WebServices",
   EnvironmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")
};
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(opts);
builder.Services.Configure<Contacts>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Contacts"));
```

Then in my StoreDataService.cs:

```
private readonly Contacts _contactSettings;
public StoreDataService(IOptions<DatabaseSettings> dbSettings, IOptions<Contacts> contactSettings) : base(dbSettings)
{
    _dbSettings = dbSettings.Value;
    _contactSettings = contactSettings.Value;
    string[] emailList = _contactSettings.Emails;
}
```

The problem is in my emailList array I'm getting back

`[ "email1", "email2", "email5", "email6", "email7", "email8", "email9" ]`

in both Development and Production. All other fields come back correctly between the two environments. Is there something special I'm needing to do for the string array?

Comment: Have you checked that the environment is actually development?

Comment: Yes it is. When I switch to production it correctly shows e-mails 3,4,5,6,7,8 & 9. But in dev it is overwriting the first two elements with the two e-mails in the dev list.